# How can i loop through Two Lists <float> in another List? And then put the strings to a key? Almost working

Tags: c#

In the for loop i did:

```
string[] xFrames = new string[wocl.Count];
            string[] yFrames = new string[wocl.Count];
            List<float> Xframes = new List<float>(wocl.Count);
            List<float> Yframes = new List<float>(wocl.Count);
            for (int i = 0; i < wocl.Count; i++)
            {
                string X = xFrames[i] = string.Format("Frame_X_{0} ", i + 1);
                string Y = yFrames[i] = string.Format("Frame_Y_{0} ", i + 1);

                for (int j = 0; j < wocl[i].Point_X.Count; j++)
                {
                   // xFrames[i] += string.Format("{0},", wocl[i].Point_X[j]);
                   // yFrames[i] += string.Format("{0},", wocl[i].Point_Y[j]);
                    Xframes.Add(wocl[i].Point_X[j]);
                    Yframes.Add(wocl[i].Point_X[j]);

                }

                //xFrames[i].Trim(",".ToCharArray());
                //yFrames[i].Trim(",".ToCharArray());

                setting_file.SetListFloatKey(X, Xframes);
                setting_file.SetListFloatKey(Y, Yframes);

            }
```

The result in the text file is:

```
Frame_X_1 =325,332,322,332,325
Frame_Y_1 =325,332,322,332,325
Frame_X_2 =325,332,322,332,325,318,332,322,332,325
Frame_Y_2 =325,332,322,332,325,318,332,322,332,325
Frame_X_3 =325,332,322,332,325,318,332,322,332,325,318,332,322,355,325
Frame_Y_3 =325,332,322,332,325,318,332,322,332,325,318,332,322,355,325
Frame_X_4 =325,332,322,332,325,318,332,322,332,325,318,332,322,355,325,318,388,322,355,325
Frame_Y_4 =325,332,322,332,325,318,332,322,332,325,318,332,322,355,325,318,388,322,355,325
```

Not sure why the numbers arel ike that on the right after the =
Should be in each Frame x and y same numbers/coordinates.

Like in  Frame_X_1 and not at Frame_X_4
or not like in Frame_X_2 For some reason its keeping adding the numbers.

The setting_file im using is connected to the OptionsFile class:

```
/*----------------------------------------------------------------
 * Module Name  : OptionsFile
 * Description  : Saves and retrievs application options
 * Author       : Danny
 * Date         : 10/02/2010
 * Revision     : 1.00
 * --------------------------------------------------------------*/

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Configuration;


/*
 *  Introduction :
 * 
 *  This module helps in saving application options
 * 
 * 
 *  Typical file could look like this:
 *  user_color=Red
 *  time_left=30
 *  
 * 
 * 
 * 
 * 
 * */

namespace DannyGeneral
{
    class OptionsFile
    {
        /*----------------------------------------
         *   P R I V A T E     V A R I A B L E S 
         * ---------------------------------------*/


        /*---------------------------------
         *   P U B L I C   M E T H O D S 
         * -------------------------------*/
        string path_exe;
        string temp_settings_file;
        string temp_settings_dir;
        string Options_File;
        StreamWriter sw;
        StreamReader sr;

/*----------------------------------------------------------
 * Function     : OptionsFile
 * Description  : Constructor
 * Parameters   : file_name is the name of the file to use
 * Return       : none
 * --------------------------------------------------------*/
    public OptionsFile(string settings)
    {
        if (!File.Exists(settings))
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists(Path.GetDirectoryName(settings)))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(settings));
            }
            File.Create(settings).Close();
        }
        path_exe = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.LocalUserAppDataPath);
        Options_File = settings; 
    }

/*----------------------------------------------------------
 * Function     : GetKey
 * Description  : gets the value of the key.
 * Parameters   : key
 * Return       : value of the key if key exist, null if not exist
 * --------------------------------------------------------*/
    public string GetKey(string key)
    {

      //  string value_of_each_key;
        string key_of_each_line;
        string line;
        int index;
        string key_value;
        key_value = null;

        sr = new StreamReader(Options_File);
        while (null != (line = sr.ReadLine()))
        {


            index = line.IndexOf("=");


           //    value_of_each_key = line.Substring(index+1);



            if (index >= 1)
            {
                key_of_each_line = line.Substring(0, index);
                if (key_of_each_line == key)
                {
                    key_value = line.Substring(key.Length + 1);
                }

            }
            else
            {
            }


        }
        sr.Close();
        return key_value;
    }


/*----------------------------------------------------------
 * Function     : SetKey
 * Description  : sets a value to the specified key
 * Parameters   : key and a value
 * Return       : none
 * --------------------------------------------------------*/
    public void SetKey(string key , string value)
    {
        bool key_was_found_inside_the_loop;
        string value_of_each_key;
        string key_of_each_line ;
        string line;
        int index;
        key_was_found_inside_the_loop = false;

        temp_settings_file = "\\temp_settings_file.txt";
        temp_settings_dir = path_exe + @"\temp_settings";
        if (!Directory.Exists(temp_settings_dir))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(temp_settings_dir);
        }

        sw = new StreamWriter(temp_settings_dir+temp_settings_file);
        sr = new StreamReader(Options_File);
        while (null != (line = sr.ReadLine()))
        {

            index = line.IndexOf("=");
            key_of_each_line = line.Substring(0, index);
            value_of_each_key = line.Substring( index + 1);
         //   key_value = line.Substring(0,value.Length);
            if (key_of_each_line == key)
            {
                sw.WriteLine(key + " = " + value);
                key_was_found_inside_the_loop = true;

            }
            else
            {
                sw.WriteLine(key_of_each_line+"="+value_of_each_key);
            }

        }

        if (!key_was_found_inside_the_loop)
        {
           sw.WriteLine(key + "=" + value);
        }
        sr.Close();
        sw.Close();
        File.Delete(Options_File);
        File.Move(temp_settings_dir + temp_settings_file, Options_File);
        return;

    }



    public List<float> GetListFloatKey(string keys)
    {
        List<float> result = new List<float>();
        string s = GetKey(keys);
        if (s != null)
        {
            string[] items = s.Split(new char[] { ',' });
            float f;
            foreach (string item in items)
            {
                if (float.TryParse(item, out f))
                    result.Add(f);
            }
            return result;
        }
        else
        {
            return result;
        }
    }


    public void SetListFloatKey(string key, List<float> Values)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (float value in Values)
        {
            sb.AppendFormat(",{0}", value);
        }
        if (Values.Count == 0)
        {
        }
        else
        {
            SetKey(key, sb.ToString().Substring(1));
        }
    }
```

Not sure whats wrong here with the numbers.

Comment: Could you explain a little better? I could not understand what you are trying to do...

Comment: "I just dont know how to loop over the wocl and then over the two Lists in each index of the wocl and make it all." Say what?

Comment: Trying to get the numbers from the Lists Point_X and Point_y that are in the List wocl. I have a list wocl and inside in each index i have two lists Point_x and Point_y and in each list i have in each index a number. I need to get the numbers from each index in the point_x and point_y according to the indexs of the wocl. if in wocl im in idex [0] so get the numbers from point_x and point_y wich are in index [0] then same for index [1] of the wocl. in each index in wocl there are the two lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use a double loop in this way:

```
string[] xFrames = new string[wocl.Count];
string[] yFrames = new string[wocl.Count];

for (int i = 0; i < wocl.Count; i++)
{
   xFrames[i] = string.Format("Frame_X_{0} ", i + 1);
   yFrames[i] = string.Format("Frame_Y_{0} ", i + 1);

   for(int j =0; j < wocl[i].Length; j++)
   {
       xFrames[i] += string.Format("{0},", wocl[i].Point_X[j]);
       yFrames[i] += string.Format("{0},", wocl[i].Point_Y[j]);
   }

   xFrames[i].Trim(",".ToCharArray());
   yFrames[i].Trim(",".ToCharArray());
}
```

Comment: I need to make somethingl ike that in the inner loop Oded: setting_file.SetListFloatKey("Frame_X_" + i.ToString(),wocl[i].Point_X[j] but thats not the way.

Comment: Oded your code is good the string's are good. What i need is that the string will be Frame_X_1 Frame_Y_1 Frame_X_2 as its now but the number on the right they need to be in a List<float> and not as string. The string only should contain the Frame_X_1...

Comment: Oded  i used your code sample but the results arent right yet. Edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

It's really hard to tell what you're trying to do. But from what I gather, you want to combine two ore more lists into some other list, by applying some sort of transformation or combination to produce the result list.

For this, I think you may want to look at the [`Enumerable.ZipEnumerable.Zip<TFirst, TSecond, TResult>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx) extension method.

As an example, if you have two lists (psuedocode):

```
val = 1, 2, 3, 4
names = "one", "two", "three", "four"
```

The Zip algorithm would allow you to combine these, say, into a list of int, string tuples:

```
result = (1,"one"), (2,"two"), (3,"three"), (4,"four")
```

Hopefully I am in the right ballpark here for what you're trying to do.

Comment: I alos added photos of the Lists how they look like: http://postimage.org/gallery/amzvlks/d5a72e83/

Comment: But i need also to add the results the string/s to the setting_file

Comment: Lol, Have you ever heard of a screenshot? Second, many people may be checking this from work, and won't (or at least their bosses won't) appreciate the scantily-clad woman on the photo hosting service you chose.

Comment: Jonathon i cant take screenshots if i click the PrtScn/SysRq/Insert button to take a screenshot in visual studio it will change the mouse cursor is there any other way to take screenshots ?

Comment: Jonathon i cant upload photos to here i dont have poulation 10 yet.

Comment: I'm not sure. I just pressed print screen with some variables expanded while debugging, and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want to iterate over iteration.

```
var output = new StringBuilder();
for(var index=0; index < wocl.Count; index++)
{
  var item = wocl[index];
  output.AppendFormat("Frame_X_{0}", index);

  for(var index2=0; index2 < item.Point_X.Count; index2++ )
  {
     output.AppendFormat(" {0}", item.Point_X[index2]);
  }

  output.AppendFormat("Frame_Y_{0}", index);

  for(var index2=0; index2 < item.Point_Y.Count; index2++ )
  {
     output.AppendFormat(" {0}", item.Point_Y[index2]);
  }
}

string resultText = output.ToString();
```

Comment: You are missing the commas between the inner array values.

Comment: Forgot to mention that i need to put the strings into a key. I will edit my question.